Foundations researching on activity-based projects in school level
I have introduced a humanistic mathematics activity-based project for students from grade six to grade eleven in my school. I am interested in gathering information from foundations that are actively working in this area and would like to share experiences and insights with them. Could you please provide references to relevant organizations or initiatives for this purpose? 
For further clarification following are the guidelines used in my project.

Historical Awareness: Activities should help students understand the development of mathematics over generations, fostering an appreciation of its historical context and evolution.

Foundation for Advanced Mathematics: Select activities that are robust and substantial, serving as a strong foundation for further exploration and extensions in advanced mathematical concepts.

Practical Importance: Ensure that the activities have clear and meaningful real-life applications, demonstrating the practical relevance and utility of mathematics in everyday life.

Encouragement of Alternative Approaches: Opt for activities that invite and support diverse problem-solving methods, allowing students to explore and propose alternative approaches.

Independence from Physical Objects: Choose activities that can be performed by students independently, without the need for any physical objects, ensuring accessibility and ease of implementation.



Could you specify by some examples you already use what this " humanistic mathematics activity-based project " is exactly?  For example historic means to establish the radius of earth, the size of moon compared to earth, the distance  to the sun compared to distance to moon.would these apply?

https://scholarship.claremont.edu/jhm/

Your wishes seem to be quite usual in the didactics of mathematics communities I am aware of, maybe aside from the independence on physical objects, as the use of concrete, manipulable items is also often favoured.
As such, I would look at any database of mathematics activities associated with researchers in didactics of mathematics. I doubt all of the activities will fulfill all of your needs, but many will cover a lot of them.
In Norway, I would either contact any university or høgskole that deals in teacher education, or just Matematikksenteret. For examples of activities I would look at Matte-LIST that they maintain.
Other countries are likely to have their communities of mathematics education. In Finland I would contact either universities dealing with teacher education or LUMA-keskus.
